# GRX800 position

Tags: derailleur, alignment, hanger, grx

I got a bike from chainreaction with GRX groupset on it.
The rear derailleur is not aligned with the cassette.
I think the hanger got bent during delivery, but the guy at the local shop says it's fine.
It works kind of fine, but not better than my previous lower-level setup. And it's slightly lagging on high gears.
It's my first 1-by, so, I'm not sure if it's normal.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It’s not always easy to tell from photos but the hanger does look pretty bent

Comment: The shop should be able to whip off the rear derailleur, bolt on a derailleur straightness gauge, and test it around your wheel in a few minutes.  Are they just a bike seller not a LBS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely does not look fine from the pictures. The pulleys should be in line with the cogs.

Hanger alignment is an extremely common issue that keeps things from being good to go out of the box on direct-to-consumer bikes. It's not surprising or weird for new DTC bikes to need it, even if everything else about the pre-assembly was great.

It's always possible for the misalignment to be in the derailleur and not the hanger, but that's not usually what happens.

It's not clear what the shop you took it to did beyond just eyeball it, if anything. Eyeballing it is really not enough anymore. Your best plan is to get someone to align the hanger and make it perfect. At that point the RD is re-attached and the visual you then get on how good the alignment is should be reflective of whether there's any distortion to the RD itself, which there hopefully (and usually) isn't. The RD may need to be re-adjusted at that point, or everything may come to life and be great since it was likely adjusted when it was aligned before getting boxed up.

Answer (score 1):

It took some time because I just moved to Warsaw, Poland, and had to find English-speaking shops.
I found 2, and at both of them, I've been told that the only tool to check the hanger straightness is the eye of the master. Both masters said the hanger is perfectly straight and they would have to bend the mech itself.
The second guy had the entire Parktool set, so, I spotted the right tool, showed him a youtube video on how to use it and we did it together.
It's much better now, not ideal, but it will do until I find the replacement. The lagging is gone too.
Thanks for the help!
[image]

Comment: Thanks for following up!